# Can't find error? PHP Mandrill Backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The following code isn't working, any ideas why? We are creating a backend with PHP using Mandrill.  We are doing this so our API will not be visible to visitors who do inspect element.    Many Thanks!

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src='http://qtip2.com/static/javascripts/libs/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://qtip2.com/static/javascripts/libs/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
 </head>

<body>

<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email address</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Message</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="7"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" id="captchaOperation"></label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
  $('#contactForm')
.formValidation({

})
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
    // Prevent default form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(e.target);

    // Send all form data to back-end
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/your/send-mail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            // Clear the form
            $form.formValidation('resetForm', true);

            // Regenerate the captcha
            generateCaptcha();

             // Show the message
            response.result === 'error'
                ? $('#alertContainer')
                    .removeClass('alert-success')
                    .addClass('alert-warning')
                    .html('Sorry, cannot send the message')
                    .show()
                : $('#alertContainer')
                    .removeClass('alert-warning')
                    .addClass('alert-success')
                    .html('Your message has been successfully sent')
                    .show();
        }
    });
});
```

PHP (file path is just /send-mail.php)

```
<?php
// send-mail.php

// Download Mandrill PHP library from
// https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php/get/master.zip
require_once '/path/to/Mandrill.php';

try {
// See https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.php.html
$mandrill = new Mandrill('API KEY');

// Build the message body
$body     = array(
    '<strong>Name:</strong> ' + $_POST['firstName'] + ' ' + $_POST['lastName'],
    '<strong>Phone number:</strong> ' + isset($_POST['phoneNumber']) ? $_POST['phoneNumber'] : 'n/a',
    '<strong>Message:</strong> ',
    $_POST['message'],
);
$body     = implode('<br/>', $body);

$message  = array(
    'html'       => $body,
    'subject'    => 'Contact form',
    'from_email' => $_POST['email'],
    'from_name'  => $_POST['firstName'] + ' ' + $_POST['lastName'],
    'to'         => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'myemail@email.com',
            'name'  => 'Me',
            'type'  => 'to'
        )
    ),
    'headers'    => array(
        'Reply-To' => 'message.reply@example.com'
    ),
);
$async  = false;
$result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async);

echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => 'ok',
));
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => 'error',
  ));
```

}

Comment: remove the multiple adding scripts of jquery this cause some conflicts remove them and try once

Comment: require_once('your.file'); But what is the error your getting? If it is a 500 its probably php syntax. If not then check the console log for javascript error.